# (up to) 30 minute delay in AWS Lambda function logging to show up in CloudWatch Console Log Stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm seeing a change that really just started yesterday afternoon, Wednesday April 6th approximately 14:00 GMT. I used to be able to trigger a Lambda function (in my case I'm using API Gateway) and I could normally see the relevant log entries show up in the AWS CloudWatch Console usually within a few seconds. As of yesterday, the logs are taking maybe up 30 minutes to show up and I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced anything similar or could point me in the right direction to check things out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: same problem,  seeing ~20-22 minutes delay on my logs :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm going to answer (close) this question out ... a few hours ago the delay stopped. I'm now able to see logs appear in CloudWatch within a few seconds of the lambda fn. completing. Thanks all